# Azure "App Service" - Django and SQLite

Tags: python, django, sqlite, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a django app (specifically django-rest). When I run the local copy of this site, my requests can be processed in 50-400ms.

Next, I managed to deploy to Microsoft Azure App Service. Now, under the most expensive tier I can buy, responses are coming back in the 800-2000ms range.

The app does simple queries on sqlite database. This database file is approximately 30 megabytes with the largest table is 12000 rows.

I should point out all access to the database is read only, so no contention issues.

Configuration:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'mydatabase.db'),
    }
}
```

web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="WSGI_ALT_VIRTUALENV_HANDLER" value="django.core.wsgi.get_wsgi_application()" />
    <add key="WSGI_ALT_VIRTUALENV_ACTIVATE_THIS" value="D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\Scripts\activate_this.py" />
    <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="ptvs_virtualenv_proxy.get_virtualenv_handler()" />
    <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="D:\home\site\wwwroot" />
    <add key="DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE" value="myapp.settings" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <!-- Required for websockets. -->
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="Python273_via_FastCGI" />
      <add name="Python FastCGI" path="handler.fcgi" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="D:\Python27\python.exe|D:\Python27\Scripts\wfastcgi.py" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" />
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Static Files" stopProcessing="true">
          <conditions>
            <add input="true" pattern="false" />
          </conditions>
        </rule>
        <rule name="Configure Python" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/static/.*" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="handler.fcgi/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Python version 2.7.

I have narrowed it down to SQLite performance. Static files and API index pages come back in ~60ms while the heaviest query comes back in ~2000ms. This is Time Till First Byte, and not overall response times, and I have ruled out network latency (which is very low due to the geographic proximity). This is on P3 (Premium Tier) 4 core, 7GB ram (as Azure calls it).

Running on localhost, the response times are ~15ms for index pages, and ~380ms for the same requests on my Macbook 2.2 GHz Intel Core i7 16 GB 1600 MHz DDR3.

App "warm-up" is not the issue as this is after its already "hot" (timing is based on a few refreshes)

Update:
I installed Django Rest Toolbar for more information.

On macbook django DEV server (pure python?):

```
SQL time ~217ms
Total CPU time ~681ms

Resource    Value
User CPU time   662.771 msec
System CPU time 18.415 msec
Total CPU time  681.186 msec
Elapsed time    681.326 msec
Context switches    1 voluntary, 95 involuntary
```

On azure app service IIS and FastCGI (see config above):

```
SQL time ~854ms
Total CPU time ~2282ms
No CPU extended breakdown available.
```

Appreciate any insight!

Comment: How many instance does your web app have? After the long response time, does the data are correct? How do you deploy your SqlLite database?

Comment: 1 instance, only me hitting the API. The sqlite database is a file, deployed via GIT (30 MB file).

Comment: if you suspect that sqlite is the culprit look at the sql tab in debug-toolbar and see how many queries show up in there and what is the slowest

Comment: However it's also clear that your total CPU time is 3x the query time so you seem to be doing some heavy work in your view. How about posting some code?

Comment: Does your Mac have an SSD or HDD? An SSD gives a significant performance to database reads.

Comment: Given that your local and Azure test runs show a similar multiple from best to worst case and that you only have a 30MB database file, my guess is that your Azure host is simply a much slower CPU.  Looks like they do [throttling for some specs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-sizes/).

Comment: @PeterBrittain I think you are correct. If you write in answer I can accept. Just added info - this is PaaS not IaaS so it's not a VM per-say.

Comment: Well the only other solution I could imagine is that you just create a memory database and load the whole thing into it.

See https://www.sqlite.org/backup.html

Comment: Thanks - now posted.

Comment: Yes loading into memory may work out. The reality seems to be that cpu layer of the paas is not great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that your local and Azure test runs show a similar multiple from best to worst case and that you only have a 30MB database file, my guess is that your Azure host is simply a much slower CPU.

This is backed up by the fact that they do [throttling for some spec VMs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-sizes/).  It is also something that has been noted in [comparison to AWS](https://www.pythian.com/blog/comparing-cpu-throughput-of-azure-and-aws-ec2/).  I imagine the same is true for your App Service platform.

Comment: Turns out the issue was SQLite and I/O performance. It is very bad because their front end servers are distributed and work over a slow... networked file system. Switching to SQL server is the only solution.

Comment: Presumably that's because they guarantee better disk IO for their SQL server offerings.